Is $\text{SAT}$ 2-self-reducible?
We say that a language  is -self-reducible if there exists a function  such that:

  is computable in polynomial time, and
There exists $_0 ∈ ℕ$ such that for all  of length at least $_0$, the function  returns a list of  strings $_1, _2, … , _$ that are all shorter than  (i.e., $|_| < ||$ for all $1 ≤  ≤ $), and in addition $ ∈  ⟺$ There exists $$ such that $_ ∈ .$

Is  $\text{SAT}$ 2-self-reducible?
My attempt: I think, Yes, SAT is 2-self-reducible. Given a Boolean formula  $\phi$ , we can create two shorter formulas  $\phi_1$ and  $\phi_2$  by assigning one variable  $x$  to true and false, respectively. Then,  $\phi \in \text{SAT} \iff \phi_1 \in \text{SAT}$  or  $\phi_2 \in \text{SAT}$ , satisfying the conditions of 2-self-reducibility.
I don't know my approach is correct track or not. Anybody help to give me the better proof.

It seems correct for me
